# flexible space vs fixed space bar button item

Tags: objective-c

flexible space vs fixed space bar button items, what's the difference ? I couldn't find any definition on the internet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The flexible space adjusts its size as the window is resized.

Comment: thank you for the answer ( i don't know why the question is rated down)